# Text recognition model improvement suggestions

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, ocr

I am trying to make a text recognition model using CNNs and LSTMs with CTC Loss. My current model looks like this where the numbers in bracket are the shape of tensor after each layer. I have a vocabulary size of 94 and size of my input image is (64x1024). This model is improving very slowly and I need some thought if I can change some thing. Thanks :)

```
Input: (?, 64, 1024, 1)
cnn-1: [None, 64, 1024, 64]
bn-1: [None, 64, 1024, 64]
relu-1: [None, 64, 1024, 64]
maxpool-1: [None, 32, 512, 64]
cnn-2: [None, 32, 512, 128]
bn-2: [None, 32, 512, 128]
relu-2: [None, 32, 512, 128]
maxpool-2: [None, 16, 256, 128]
cnn-3: [None, 16, 256, 128]
bn-3: [None, 16, 256, 128]
relu-3: [None, 16, 256, 128]
maxpool-3: [None, 8, 128, 128]
cnn-4: [None, 8, 128, 256]
bn-4: [None, 8, 128, 256]
relu-4: [None, 8, 128, 256]
maxpool-4: [None, 4, 64, 256]
cnn-5: [None, 4, 64, 256]
bn-5: [None, 4, 64, 256]
relu-5: [None, 4, 64, 256]
maxpool-5: [None, 2, 32, 256]
lstm-input: [None, 32, 512]
lstm-output: [None, 32, 64]
lstm-output-reshaped: [None, 64]
fully-connected: [None, 94]
reshaped_logits: [None, None, 94]
transposed_logits: [None, None, 94]
```

Comment: consider posting this question in [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: the architecture looks ok. Are you inputting images of single text lines? Have you checked the tensor shapes, sometimes (RNN vs. CTC) the ordering of the axis differs (T, B, C). Which optimizer do you use? I'm using RMSPropOptimizer(0.001).

Comment: Yup. My input images are mostly 2-4 words. And yes, I am transposing the logits by `logits = tf.transpose(logits, (1, 0, 2))` before putting it through CTC loss.(If thats what you meant by ordering of the axes). I am using Adam with initial lr=1e-3, beta1 = 0.9, beta2 = 0.999.

Comment: When I used Adam, I set LR=0.1, the other parameters use the default values of TF. You said your model takes long to improve (slow convergence), therefore try increasing the LR (e.g. try the value 0.1 which I used).